# Python Variable

Tags: python, terminal

I am a beginner with python, and I'm having trouble with a program I'm making.  Here is the code.

```
import random

s1 = "*"
s2 = "*"
s3 = "*"
s4 = "*"
s5 = "*"
s6 = "*"
s7 = "*"
s8 = "*"
s9 = "*"


Spaces = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9]


def Board():
    print ""
    print "",s1,"|",s2,"|",s3
    print "","---------"
    print "",s4,"|",s5,"|",s6
    print "","---------"
    print "",s7,"|",s8,"|",s9, "\n"


def PlayerMove():
    move = raw_input('Choose a space 1-9 \n')

    if move == "1":
        s1 = "X"
    elif move == "2":
        s2 = "X"
    elif move == "3":
        s3 = "X"
    elif move == "4":
        s4 = "X"
    elif move == "5":
        s5 = "X"
    elif move == "6":
        s6 = "X"
    elif move == "7":
        s7 = "X"
    elif move == "8":
        s8 = "X"
    elif move == "9":
        s9 = "X"
    Board()


def Computer1():
    random.choice(Spaces)
    if random.choice(Spaces) == "s1":
        s1 = "X"
    elif random.choice(Spaces) == 's3':
        s3 = "X"
    elif random.choice(Spaces) == 's5':
        s5 = "X"
    elif random.choice(Spaces) == 's7':
        s7 = "X"
    elif random.choice(Spaces) == 's9':
        s9 = "X"
    Board()


PlayerMove()
Computer1()
```

When i run this code in terminal however, i get the following:

```
Choose a space 1-9 
1

 * | * | *
 ---------
 * | * | *
 ---------
 * | * | * 


 * | * | *
 ---------
 * | * | *
 ---------
 * | * | *
```

Basically, I want to make it so the functions PlayerMove() and Computer1() do the following:

When the code runs PlayerMove(), I want the input to change the variable s1, (or s2, or s3... depending on the input), to a new value (that value being X).
When the code runs Computer1(), I want the random.choice take a random choice from the list Spaces, and if the space chosen is one of the following, change the value of s1 (or s3, s5, s7, s9) to X.

How would i make it so that this change happens, and if i call the Board() function, it prints the board with these changes?

Comment: You should strongly consider ditching the `sN` variables in favour of a nine-element `list`. You would find the code suddenly became much simpler... And explicit parameters and `return` values would be better than relying on scope for e.g. `Spaces`.

Comment: this looks like homework

Comment: its not homework, but a little help would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the `sN` variables inside functions `PlayerMove()` and `ComputerMove()`, you have to declare them as [global](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) in the beginning of the function.

```
def PlayerMove():
    global s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9
    move = raw_input('Choose a space 1-9 \n')
    ...
```

But as mentioned earlier, you should consider using an array or list to hold the state of the board instead of individual variables for each cell.

```
board = [["*", "*", "*"],
         ["*", "*", "*"],
         ["*", "*", "*"]]
```

Now you can access the state of the board

```
 board[1][1] # => "*"
 board[1][1] = 'X'
 board[1][1] # => "X"
```

Comment: thanks so much, how would i make an array instead of the board though.

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import cycle

EMPTY   = "*"
PLAYER1 = "X"
PLAYER2 = "O"

class Board:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bd = [EMPTY] * 9
        self.who = cycle([PLAYER1, PLAYER2])

    def __str__(self):
        return (
            "\n"
            " {} | {} | {}\n"
            " ---------\n"
            " {} | {} | {}\n"
            " ---------\n"
            " {} | {} | {}\n"
        ).format(*(self.bd))

    def open_moves(self):
        return [i for i,ch in enumerate(self.bd, 1) if ch==EMPTY]

    def do_move(self, where):
        if self.bd[where - 1] == EMPTY:
            self.bd[where - 1] = next(self.who)
        else:
            raise ValueError("That space is already occupied")
```

which can be used like

```
>>> bd = Board()
>>> bd.open_moves()
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> bd.do_move(5)
>>> print(bd)

 * | * | *
 ---------
 * | X | *
 ---------
 * | * | *
```